# .each loop in jquery that finds all anchors pointing to specifc location and changes the class

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

I need to loop through my website using jquery and change the class selector of all `<a>` elements which have `href=#`. I have this much but am not sure how to write the "for/each" portion in jquery.. any help out there?

```
if($("a.cs-wowslider-images-new").attr('href') == "#"){
$("a.cs-wowslider-images-new").removeClass("wow-fancy");
alert('removed');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...all you were missing was the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$("a").each(function(idx) {
  if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {
    $(this).removeClass('whateverClass');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for an `each` block if the desired operation is also available as a jQuery function:

```
$('a[href="#"]').removeClass('wow-fancy');
```

jQuery functions *expect* to be passed an *array* of matching elements, and in most cases will automatically apply the function to each element on that array.

Comment: Thanks, alnitak.. where should I place this in my code? What's happening is that there is another bit of Jquery that is dynamically changing the class for all `<a>`s and I want to remove 'wow-fancy' from those whose href = #

Comment: lol.. thanks, alnitak.. I tried it but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the page.. here's the page http://freemanfoxx.com and here's the JS file I edited with your line of code (your code is at the very bottom): http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/wp-content/themes/freemanfoxx/js/2wows-squares.js

Comment: enclose it in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... } )` block.  At the moment it's actually being run _before_ the rest of the jQuery code. That block will make it run after.

Comment: hmm.. nope.. I enclosed it in in the document.ready like you said and it still doesn't execute correctly.. any more thoughts? This thing has been driving me crazy for 3 days now..

Comment: Ah, you presumably have _other_ JS files that are calling this one.  Best put it in your very own JS file which you ensure is loaded last.

Comment: :-(.. nope.. now it's for sure loading last but still same deal.. the freakin' class selector wow-fancy is not going away

Comment: I don't see it when I load your site in Chrome.

Comment: right before end of body tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/wp-content/themes/freemanfoxx/js/2wows-squares-fix.js"></script>`

Comment: I also added a `alert('hi')` just to test and for sure it is there

Comment: I mean I don't see any elements with that class - I see your code OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at some of the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). E.g. the following selector returns all links that point to an anchor (href starting with # pointing to a named anchor) using the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('input[href^="#"]').each(function() {
    // do something with $(this)
});
```